# ¿Porque me aparece la misma fecha en todos los Usuarios?

Tags: java, mysql

estoy en Java, y quiero mostrar los usuarios que tengo en la base de datos, hago la consulta y me la recoge bien, los inserto bien en un ArrayList y cuando lo muestro solamente me aparece la fecha de nacimiento del último usuario. ¿Porqué?

```
try {
        sentencia = conexion.createStatement();
        String consulta = 
                "SELECT Nombre, Apellidos, Telefono, Fecha_Nacimiento, "
                + "Domicilio, Ciudad, DNI, Bloqueado, Usuario, Tipo FROM usuarios;";
        ResultSet resultado = sentencia.executeQuery(consulta);
        while (resultado.next()) {
            calendario.set(Integer.parseInt(resultado.getString(4).substring(0, 4)), 
                Integer.parseInt(resultado.getString(4).substring(5, 7)),
                Integer.parseInt(resultado.getString(4).substring(8, 10)));
            mostrarUsuario = new Usuario(resultado.getString(1), resultado.getString(2),
            resultado.getInt(3), calendario, resultado.getString(5), resultado.getString(6),
            resultado.getString(7), resultado.getString(8).charAt(0), resultado.getString(9),
            resultado.getString(10).charAt(0));
            listaUsuarios.add(mostrarUsuario);
            System.out.println(mostrarUsuario.toString());
        }
        resultado.close();
        // MOSTRAMOS LOS USUARIOS
        mostrarUsuarios();
    } catch (NumberFormatException | SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "ERROR AL CARGAR DATOS DE LA BASE DE DATOS\n"
                + "Detalles del Error: " + e.getMessage(), "Error en el catch", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

private void mostrarUsuarios() {
    try {
        // MODELO DE LA TABLA
        String[] columnas = {"Nombre", "Apellidos", "Nº Teléfono", 
            "Fecha Nacimiento", "Domicilio", "Ciudad", "DNI", "Bloqueado", "Usuario", "Tipo"};
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null, columnas);
        for (Usuario mostrar : listaUsuarios) {
            calendario.set(mostrar.getFechaNacimiento().get(Calendar.YEAR),
              mostrar.getFechaNacimiento().get(Calendar.MONTH), mostrar.getFechaNacimiento().get(Calendar.DATE));
            String[] filas = {mostrar.getNombre(), mostrar.getApellidos(),
                String.valueOf(mostrar.getTelefono()), 
                String.valueOf(calendario.get(Calendar.DATE) + "-" + calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH)
                + "-" + calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR)), mostrar.getDomicilio(), 
                mostrar.getCiudad(), mostrar.getDni(), String.valueOf(mostrar.getBloqueado()),
                mostrar.getUsuario(), String.valueOf(mostrar.getTipo())};
            modelo.addRow(filas);
            tablaUsuarios.setModel(modelo);
            System.out.println(mostrar.toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Salida:
Cargarusuario:

Samuel', 'a', '987654321', '2018-7-9', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'N', 'Usuario', 'null', 'A asdasd', 'Apellidos', '123456789', '2018-10-9', 'Domicilio', 'Ciudad', 'd', 'N', 'AAAAAAAA', 'null', 'N Kia', 'ape', '656298534', '2008-11-26', 'Villa pelisa', 'pelusoide', '5454564', 'N', 'kia', 'null', 'T

MostrarUsuario :
Samuel', 'a', '987654321', '2008-11-26', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'N', 'Usuario', 'null', 'A
asdasd', 'Apellidos', '123456789', '2008-11-26', 'Domicilio', 'Ciudad', 'd', 'N', 'AAAAAAAA', 'null', 'N
Kia', 'ape', '656298534', '2008-11-26', 'Villa pelisa', 'pelusoide', '5454564', 'N', 'kia', 'null', 'T

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Usuarios;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 *
 * @author Programador
 */
public class Usuario {
    private String nombre, apellidos, domicilio, ciudad, dni, usuario, contrasena;
    private int telefono;
    private char bloqueado, tipo;
    private Calendar fechaNacimiento = Calendar.getInstance();

    // CONSTRUCTOR PARAMETRIZADO
    public Usuario(String nombre, String apellidos, int telefono, Calendar fechaNacimiento, 
            String domicilio, String ciudad, String dni, char bloqueado, String usuario,
            String contrasena, char tipo) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
        this.domicilio = domicilio;
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.bloqueado = bloqueado;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.contrasena = contrasena;
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    // CONSTRUCTOR PARAMETRIZADO PARA MOSTRAR LOS DATOS
    Usuario(String nombre, String apellidos, int numTelefono, Calendar fechaNacimiento,
            String domicilio, String ciudad, String dni, char bloqueado, String usuario, char tipo) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.telefono = numTelefono;
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
        this.domicilio = domicilio;
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.bloqueado = bloqueado;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public String getDomicilio() {
        return domicilio;
    }

    public void setDomicilio(String domicilio) {
        this.domicilio = domicilio;
    }

    public String getCiudad() {
        return ciudad;
    }

    public void setCiudad(String ciudad) {
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
    }

    public String getDni() {
        return dni;
    }

    public void setDni(String dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getContrasena() {
        return contrasena;
    }

    public void setContrasena(String contrasena) {
        this.contrasena = contrasena;
    }

    public int getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(int telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public char getBloqueado() {
        return bloqueado;
    }

    public void setBloqueado(char bloqueado) {
        this.bloqueado = bloqueado;
    }

    public char getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(char tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public Calendar getFechaNacimiento() {
        return fechaNacimiento;
    }

    public void setFechaNacimiento(Calendar fechaNacimiento) {
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nombre + "', '" + apellidos + "', '" + telefono + "', '" + (fechaNacimiento.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            + "-" + fechaNacimiento.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "-" + fechaNacimiento.get(Calendar.DATE)) + "', '"
                + domicilio + "', '" + ciudad + "', '" + dni + "', '" +
                bloqueado + "', '" + usuario + "', '" + contrasena + "', '" + tipo;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé de qué tipo es la variable `calendario` (supongo que Calendar), pero el problema que tienes es que nunca la re-inicializas, sino que reutilizas el mismo objeto una y otra vez, modificándolo.

Por tanto, la última modificación es la que cuenta, puesto que todos los usuarios comparten la misma instancia.

Lo normal es que usases objetos de la clase `Date` para guardar fechas y simplemente usases la clase Calendar para generarlos (aunque si trabajas con Java 8 o posterior deberías mirar las clases del paquete `java.time`). En cualquier caso te pongo el código que resuelve el problema tal y como tienes la clase usuario.

```
 while (resultado.next()) {
     Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance(); //nueva instancia dentro del bucle       calendario.set(Integer.parseInt(resultado.getString(4).substring(0, 4)), 
     Integer.parseInt(resultado.getString(4).substring(5, 7)),
     Integer.parseInt(resultado.getString(4).substring(8, 10)));
     mostrarUsuario = new Usuario(resultado.getString(1), resultado.getString(2),
     resultado.getInt(3), calendario, resultado.getString(5), resultado.getString(6),
     resultado.getString(7), resultado.getString(8).charAt(0), resultado.getString(9),
     resultado.getString(10).charAt(0));
     listaUsuarios.add(mostrarUsuario);
     System.out.println(mostrarUsuario.toString());
 }
```

La clase Date no es inmutable, como sí lo es la clase [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) pero deberías tratarla como tal para evitar problemas.

Comment: Upp perdon, Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance(); Gracias por contestar Pablo, pero aunque cree otra variable calendario2 y se lo asigne a mostrar, me vuelve a sacar lo mismos datos.

Comment: Añade a la pregunta el código de la clase Usuario para poder verificar qué pasa, por favor

Comment: Si, usaba Date pero esta obsoleta dicha Clase, por eso uso la clase Calendar.

Comment: Te he puesto el código tal cual creo que deberías tenerlo usando Calendar, pero deberías usar Date (lo obsoleto no es la clase en sí, sino la mayoría de sus métodos)

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo, pero el error no esta al cargarlo desde mysql, es al mostrarlo, cuando lo guardo en el arraylist lo guarda bien, pero cuando lo muestro es cuando no me sale la fecha bien.

Comment: Seguro? El código de `mostrarUsuarios()` no modifica los usuarios antes de mostrarlos con `System.out.println(mostrar.toString());`. El problema no está ahí

Comment: Sí, esto es la salida antes de meter al usuario en el ArrayList: Samuel', 'a', '987654321', '2018-7-9', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'N', 'Usuario', 'null', 'A asdasd', 'Apellidos', '123456789', '2018-10-9', 'Domicilio', 'Ciudad', 'd', 'N', 'AAAAAAAA', 'null', 'N Kia', 'ape', '656298534', '2008-11-26', 'Villa pelisa', 'pelusoide', '5454564', 'N', 'kia', 'null', 'T,

Comment: Si, cuando creo al nuevo usuario si lo realiza correctamente, pero cuando ya el usuario es insertado en el ArrayList y lo muestra es cuando las fechas son iguales. Pero al cargar de la base de datos lo carga bien los datos.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85651/discussion-between-samuel-tena-and-pablo-lozano).